# Help proving and counting functions.

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $\mathscr F$ denote the set of all functions from $\{1, 2, 3\}$ to $\{1, 2, 3\}$.

a) Of the two following statements, one is true and one is false. Prove the true statement. Write out the negation of the false statement and prove it.

For all $f \in\mathscr F$, there exists $g \in\mathscr F$ so that $g(f(1))=2$.

For all $f \in\mathscr F$, there exists $g \in\mathscr F$ so that $f(g(1))=2$.

b) Let $f \in\mathscr F$ be defined by $f(1)=2$, $f(2)=3$ and $f(3)=2$. Find and simplify the number
of functions $g \in\mathscr F$ so that $f(g(f(1))) = 2$. Explain.

I'm not sure how to go about this question as I'm not sure what $f$ or $g$ is so I don't know how to determine what $f(1)$ or $g(f(1))$ would be. I guess I'm looking for insight on what how to look at functions with regards to discrete mathematics.

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**: Given an arbitrary function $f\in\mathscr F$, is there necessarily some $n$ such that $f(n)=2$? If not, then the second statement in the first part is false. (Why?)

If $f$ is defined as in part (b) and $f(g(f(1)))=2,$ then what can $g(f(1))$ be? Equivalently, what can $g(2)$ be?

Comment: I believe that there is not necessarily some n such that f(n)=2 because it does not specifically state the function is onto (I feel there is a better way to explain this but I'm having troubles coming up with the correct terminology). So then the second statement would be false.

For the first statement, could I do something like let the function g be defined by g:{1, 2, 3} to {2} so then regardless of what f is, g(f) would be 2?

Comment: For part b), for f(g(f(1)))=2, g(f(1)) would have to equal 1. So the function g would have to be defined as g: {1, 2, 3} to {1}?

Comment: Oh, g(f(1)) can also equal 3. So g(f(1))=g(2)=1 or 3 so there are two functions, or do I need to consider g(1) and g(3)?

Comment: @Ian: What you say in your first comment about the first statement is correct: if we set $g(x)=2$ for all $x\in\{1,2,3\}$, then $g(f(1))=2$ no matter what $f$ is. For the other half, what if $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in\{1,2,3\}$? Is there any $g$ that will make $f(g(1))=2$? // Yes, in (b) $f(1)=2$, so $g(f(1))=g(2)$, and we have to choose $g$ so that $f(g(2))=2$, so we must have $g(2)=1$ or $g(2)=3$. Are there any restrictions on what $g(1)$ and $g(3)$ can be?

Comment: @Ian: Sorry for not getting back to you sooner (sleeping). Fortunately, Brian happened along.

Comment: There would be no restrictions on what g(1) or g(3) can be, so would there be 2*3*3=18 functions?

Comment: @Ian: Exactly right. Nicely done.